# Monotonic relationship with plateaus and vertical portions?

Tags: monotone-functions

For a monotonic relationship between $x$ and $y$, an increase $x$ always leads to an increase in $y$ or always leads to a decrease in $y$.  On a graph, the slope is always positive or always negative.

What is an almost monotonic relationship called if some portions of the curve are horizontal or vertical?